# Does Size of Table include Index?

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to find the size of a table in my database.

I used the following :

`sp_spaceused [Test1_NoCompression]`

and got the following results :

[image: Table Info]

My question is : What is the total size of this table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning both?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx

Total size of table is in column reserverd, or data + index_size + unused